# Unable to pass variable value within classes in android

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

### MAIN CLASS

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    Button login;
    TextView sett;

    @Override
    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView sett = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(
                           Main.this,
                           Authenticate.class);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
// remaining code.......
```

### Authentication class (the called class)

```
public class Authenticate extends Activity {
Main Instance = new Main();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.authenticate);  

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {             
       Instance.sett.setText("activity started, thread started, success!!");
            
            
    }
        }).start();

    }
```

}
I get a null pointer exception error with the above code.
The code runs successfully if the textview variable is defined in the authenticate class,

### logcat

```
      12-18 16:49:15.219: D/dalvikvm(2747): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1901K, 41% free 2990K/5032K,       paused 8ms+95ms, total 181ms
   12-18 16:49:15.330: W/Trace(2747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   12-18 16:49:15.330: W/dalvikvm(2747): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
    12-18 16:49:15.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2747): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-198
    12-18 16:49:15.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2747): java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-18 16:49:15.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2747):     at com.example.myproject.Authenticate$1.run(Authenticate.java:21)
   12-18 16:49:15.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2747):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    12-18 16:49:15.359: W/Trace(2747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
     12-18 16:49:15.359: W/Trace(2747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
     12-18 16:49:15.379: W/Trace(2747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    12-18 16:49:15.379: W/Trace(2747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   12-18 16:49:15.419: W/Trace(2747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

---

also tried static TextView sett; in main class and Main.sett.setText("activity started, thread started, success!!"); in authenticate class file still getting the null pointer error

Answer (score 0):

You can't create Activities using `new`. The correct way to do this is to start the Authenticate activity with `startActivityForResult()` and then finish and send the result back when the authentication succeeds.

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

Comment: butI can successfully switch to the activity the problem is gettin the variable Textview to the other  (Authenticate) activity.. do check the edit after logcat

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you send the text in the TextView over as an String extra.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Authenticate.class);
i.putExtra("textNeeded", sett.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

In the authentication activity you can use this in the onCreate() to get the text:

```
String text = getIntent.getStringExtra("textNeeded");
```

Answer (score -2):

Just make sett `static` then you don't need the instance

Comment: thanks.. but what if the variable is not static ie. the value is entered by the user and i want to show that.

Comment: thats no problem you can change the value of it as often as you want

Comment: nope.. I did static TextView sett; in main class and Main.sett.setText("activity started, thread started, success!!"); in authenticate class file still getting the null pointer error